# How to save a QGIS workspace with database link for offline use?

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, sql-server

Is it possible to save current workspace of QGIS for offline usage like in mapinfo? **My workspace has link to database.** and when I reopen workspace unlink in mapinfo it can't open it.

Comment: what database are you using

Comment: @NathanW I am using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 2):

Database linked tables are a MapInfo construct but can be replicated

The best bet would be to extract your data via ogr2ogr
If you make changes you would upload it back to your database

You could run an action on the table in QGIS to run this download / upload  each time you need to refresh or load your changes into the db

Comment: for 100 users this would be lot of problem :( .

Answer (score 0):

There is such a solution for offline work and merging results together but it requires PostGIS as a backend.

http://www.sourcepole.ch/offline-editing-plugin-for-qgis

Comment: you mean it required database connection to be live always. I wanted to work in a condition where there is not internet or intranet exactly like mapinfo does.

Comment: offline editing plugin does not need a permanent internet connection. it does what you want but only with PostGIS not SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to load SQL Server Express onto your users' workstation pc and setup replication with your central database. This way all your users will maintain connection to their replicated versions of the data and you can manage the transactions back to the server when they are connected to your network.